# Not able to access JsonDicomConverter in .net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dicom, fo-dicom

I am trying to extract data from **Dicom** files in **JSON** format using **fo-Dicom** but currently suffering from this error:

> The type or namespace name 'JsonDicomConverter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am using:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataset, new JsonDicomConverter());
```

All the header files that I am using

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using Dicom;
using Dicom.Imaging;
using Dicom.IO.Buffer;

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;
```

Why it's still saying I am missing reference?? Is JsonDicomConverter is not in the Dicom library or what am I doing wrong?? I am new in fo-Dicom and dotnet.

Comment: Looking at their GitHub code [here](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/blob/development/Serialization/Json/JsonDicomConverter.cs) I guess you need `using Dicom.Serialization;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure that you have the corresponding NuGet package installed depending on your requirement. The list of NuGet packages are given [here](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom#nuget-packages)

The `JsonDicomConverter` class is present in `Dicom.Serialization` namespace. You need to put it in your usings as `using Dicom.Serialization;` which should make your code work. Please check their GitHub [here](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/blob/development/Serialization/Json/JsonDicomConverter.cs)

Comment: No, that's not working, Can you suggest some other way?

Comment: Just wanted to be sure, have you installed the corresponding NuGet package? If so, please edit the question to show the installed packages.

Comment: Now I installed everything, Thanks @Priyank

Answer (score 2):

There is a fo-dicom.json library that I had to install using nuget package manager and now it's working.